# Socket.IO: Remove specific socket_id from room?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have a specific socket_id that I want to remove from a room in socket.io. Is there an easy way to do this? The only way I can find is to disconnect by the socket itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the client, you send your own message to the server and ask the server to remove it from the room.  The server can then use `socket.leave("someRoom")` to remove that socket from a given room.  Clients cannot join or leave rooms themselves.  Joining and leaving to/from rooms has to be done by the server (because the whole notion of chat rooms only really exists on the server).

Documentation [here](http://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket#leave(name:string[,-fn:function]):socket).

Comment: The issue is I have a socket_id on the server. The client has long-gone, so I can't access anything from the client side.

Comment: @Xenon - If the client is gone, then the socket should be disconnected already and disconnected sockets are automatically removed from any rooms. If the client is still connected, you can lookup the socket by using the socketid and then call `socket.leave()` on the socket you find.  Show us the relevant portion of your code if you want more specific coding help.

Comment: @Xenon - On the server, you can use `var socket = io.sockets.connected[socket_id]` to lookup a particular socket using the socket id.  You can then do `socket.leave("xxx)` using that socket.  But, if the socket is disconnected, it will not be in the data structure and will have already been removed from all rooms.

Comment: To 'kick' a user with socket ID `socket_id` from a room `room` of a namespace `/namespace`, you can use: `io.of('/namespace').connected['socket_id'].leave('room')`

Comment: This might be convoluted, but I have an array of my clients that I use to keep track of everything from score to unique id's... I've just yesterday realised I can store a reference to the socket in there. So, I don't think I'd need the client to ask to leave a room, I think I can just use that reference. Untested. I'll go ahead and test it... Yerp, that seems to work. (Though, I will probably run into some good reason why not to do this in the 11th hour.)

Comment: @ColinSmith - There's not enough context here to offer any advice on your comment.  Certainly a server can unilaterally remove a client from a room without the client asking for it.  If you want further advice on this topic, please post your own question, show your own code and describe what you're asking about in more detail.

Comment: Yeah, English fail this morning. I just wanted to point out that if OP stores a reference to the socket with/instead of the socket id, then accessing this function will be really easy, no need to looking things up from ids. Looking back on the question, I think I misread it.

Answer (score 0):

For socket.io version 4.0.0 upwards (Mine is version 4.4.0):

Step #1) You have to get an array of the sockets connected to that socket.id as shown in the code below.

```
//You can replace the userStatus.socketId to your own socket id, that was what I 
//used in my own case    
const userSockets = await io.of("/chat").in(userStatus.socketId).fetchSockets();
```

Step #2) After getting all the socket IDs, you will be given an array containing the individual socket (I got to know this by logging the results from the async and await fetchSockets() method that the io library on the server offered). Then use the .find() method to return the single socket object matching that same socket id again as shown below.

```
const userSocket = userSockets.find(socket => socket.id.toString() === userStatus.socketId);
```

// Replace userStatus.socketId with your own socket ID

Step #3) Remove the socket by leaving the group using the .leave() method of the socket.io library as shown below.

```
userSocket.leave(groupId);
// groupId can be replaced with the name of your room
```

Final Notes: I hope this helps someone in the future because this was what I used and it worked for me.